# Android Mobile SDK v9.2.1 closes the App once the allow button is clicked after the login is done

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I am using mobile SDK v9.2.1 for logging into the salesforce credentials, I had successfully logged in and after that allow and cancel button is shown in the screen, I had clicked the allow and taking the next action, but once clicked the allow button my app suddenly closes, please help me with the solution for this

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In My case entry point activity that was extended SalesforceActivty was having noHistory = true. so when activity launches it checks and calls LoginActivity as noHistory is true instance not maintained in the stack. after completion of the login process login activity simply get finish() and it looks like add is crashing but its just end up with not activity in the stack